# window.location slow to update after change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im experiencing an extrange behaviour with `window.location` :

I have an AJAX login, where the user gets redirected after login. The thing is that the process takes less than a second to call `window.location='admin/newPage.php'`, but then the new page status on google dev Net screen says 'pending' for over 7 seconds, then it gets finally loaded.

The server runs fine, internet is fast and `window .location` gets called fast, I have tried on chrome and firefox and same problem on both ... so Im ruling out all this problems.

Anyone else has experienced this?

Comment: What does this Google Dev thing have to do with it? I don't understand that bit.

Comment: Im just saying that on google dev to point out that the server receives the call but stays on pending for about 7 seconds before the page displays ... The code runs fine, it must eb somehting to do with the server or the page that gets loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem, Its actually the page being loaded after login.

This page has to run several server side scripts from the google server, then authenticate a user to get some google analytics data, and its being extremelly slow on that.

I just got very confused because the page didnt show for a long time. For me the spected behaviour would be  :

redirect instantly -> show blank page for 7 seconds -> show contents

instead of

stay on login for 7 seconds -> show redirect page

Answer (score 0):

After the page loaded again, javascript will trigger to load another page.
So it takes like 2x times to get to the destination if you use javascript redirection.

Comment: I already found the problem as stated in the above reply, by the way Its an ajax login process so theres no page reload.